# Genie Effect Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have requirement of implementing **Genie Effect** animation shown below.

[image]

Reference:

- https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect

I could not understand where to start. Can anyone suggest me some ideas?

I tried some code with basic animation like translation and scaling but not succeed.

Comment: did you tryied that http://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/android-special-effects-alpha-animation/

Comment: @PankajKumar, I saw your link. But it has only alpha animation and translate animation. I require curve effect. :(

Comment: Hey I was just posted that link... actually I didn't use that... Honestly I was not aware of this animation.. :)

Comment: I would like to have an accepted answer of this question. :)

Comment: Me too Waiting for accepted answer :D

Comment: Did you face any problem using BCGenieEffect? It seems to explain it nicely at that github link.

Comment: @radical, I did.. but it has iOS code. And it has different code then java. So i could not find similarity for coding concept. :(

Comment: Oh, you need it for android. You will need to read up on bezier curves and translate that code to java.

Comment: See `Canvas.drawBitmapMesh` for a way to do non-linear distortion in Android. You have Bezier curves in `Path` and can sample them with `PathMeasure`. All the pieces are there but, admittedly, putting them together is far from trivial.

Comment: @Delyan, thanks...looking forward to this.. :)

Comment: Hey, I never said I'd write it! :D I might spend some time on it over the weekend but no promises, this stuff ain't easy!

Comment: @Delyan, no no my friend.. what i mean for looking forward is will try to R&D on this myself.. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented this code with *Game Library* **AndEngine**

Kindly find the attached code below that will help u to move further..
 you can use this code as fragment to ur android code OR make instance
 of this code and again extend from activity for reusing this code.

This zip file contain 2 project :

1. Code implementation for above effect and
2. AndEngine library which u need to add to my project .

**[Click here to Download My Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5q1vv6o2bpherr/genei%20effect.rar)**

Comment: Typical solution but try to implement and let you know.. :)

Comment: ok i hv achieved animation on webview ...let me know if any issues

Comment: but i have question.. how can i set image in web view instantly? because web view will shown on screen which is currently displaying..

Comment: thats y i hv divided answer into 2 steps : 1st will show the image only second one will load when u click the button so that effect will occur .....thats to the point view when button is in android..........if u want the button should be in webview only then best part is the ajax will work good there

Comment: Hm.. but we have discussed about activity with different layouts like textview, buttons and many more. Still i have to display those first. Any event occurred and i need to capture the screen, place it to web view and then effect will occur?

Comment: right but at the least we hv to display that effect in webview other can be android components

Comment: plz let me know asap i hv did this..I HV GOT NEW SOLUTION

Comment: cool i will edit my post tonight since i implemented this code last night ..i dont hv code now :) & btw good question and it deserve bounty :P

Comment: I am not sure.. i am too busy with my project.. i just tested right now and found helpful.. don't know whether i can implement in my project or not.. :D still happy that answer found.. thanks..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43518/discussion-between-chintan-rathod-and-monica)

Comment: Did it work ? I tried it but I guess it needs 'NDK' to run. Is that true?

Comment: @Darpan nope its not NDK dependant its andengine game library is needed which is not at all huge

Comment: I guess this `andEngine` is asking for NDK, says `Execution failed for task :andEngine:compileDebugNdk, NDK not configured`

Comment: i ever configured the ndk for the same, which code r u importing apart from this code attached above?

Comment: There were two folders in downloaded `.rar. file. I imported `GeneiEffe...` as an Android project while I imported `AndEngine` as a module library in it. And this AndEngine is not getting compiled.

Comment: the other folder is lib for andengine i need not compile it , may i know which IDE are you using eclipse or android-studio? i m not sure will this lib complies on andengine u need to take a bit efforts for that :( anyways i will try to help you in case u r building into android-studio

Comment: Dropbox : That file is not anymore Please if you can share again

Comment: @KOTIOS the file on DropBox doesn't exist anymore (404), could you share it again?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make animation like **Genie Effect**. But its not as perfect as your image show, but It will help you during your research.

[Example Video of demo](http://screencast.com/t/k70jtrKOA).

Create anim folder in res. copy falling.xml

**falling.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="750"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="10%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="50%" />

    <scale
        android:duration="750"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" />

</set>
```

Use following java code to apply animaiton on button click.

```
final Animation animationFalling = AnimationUtils
                        .loadAnimation(GenieEffectActivity.this, R.anim.falling);
                imgview.startAnimation(animationFalling);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You are doing curl effect ?

Comment: Yeah.. but currently this is secondary important thing... will implement Bezier curves.

Answer (score 0):

I have a browser solution.

Check out https://github.com/kamilkp/geniejs

and http://kamilkp.github.io/ for demo.

It works in every browser including mobile (not always smoothly on firefox though). It supports Genie Effect transitions in every direction (top, bottom, left, right). It works even if the target html element is a child of some container that has overflow auto or hidden. It is library agnostic itself, but i also wrote a convenience jQuery plugin. And if you also include the html2canvas library in your project, the plugin lets you animate HTML elements with genie effect (expanding example here: http://kamilkp.co.nf/genie/canvas/)

The only requirement for the browser is that it needs to support CSS transitions. It's a pure javascript + CSS solution.

PS. You can use Phonegap to create an Android app from a web application.