# Letter posting effect or genie effect like animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to achieve animation like below:::
[image]

I have tried using scale and translation animation but not get the feel like this.

Comment: have u tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872804/1323519

Comment: you have to extend Animarion class and override applyTransformation,  in that method perform Matrix transformation using Matrix.setPolyToPoly()

Comment: thanks @pskink . I achieve this using  Matrix transformation only.

Comment: Can anyone help me with any sample as if How you have achieved it?

Comment: nominate this question to reopen @Darpan . so I can give the answer

Comment: I can't, as I don't have >3000 reputation. But  you can answer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833272/genie-effect-animation-in-android