# Genie Animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to implement genie effect inside my android app. Like if I delete one note,It goes to the specified icon in genie effect. I tried this [Genie Effect Animation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833272/genie-effect-animation-in-android) but I don't think it implements real genie effect. It just show some parts of image which are taken such that it looks like genie effect. How do I actually implement it ?

Comment: The way it is, it is just a duplicate of your linked question. If you want to get help with *specific* details, it is OK to ask a new question. But _do_ include the specific code you don't understand.

Comment: I have already told that I know that is the solution but How do I implement it ? That's what I am asking

Comment: How can i use given code in that thread in my app ? Given app doesn't work