# Animate an icon to a fixed location

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation

I have a list view and have an icon in each of the list item. I have set a `onClickLinstener` to each such 'icon' so that it animates whenever I click on them. 
What I want is called 'Genie effect'. Ie, selected icon from it's place goes to target place and disappears. I used following animation -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="-300%p" />

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0" />
</set>
```

and called it using -

```
final Animation animationFalling = AnimationUtils
                        .loadAnimation(GIFDemo.this, R.anim.bookmark);
                animationFalling.setFillAfter(true);
                imageView.startAnimation(animationFalling);
```

(I want icon selected in blue box to reach 'blue icon' on top-center, though I am not able to achieve when in listview)

[image]

PS - I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19872804/609782) though I figured out it needs NDK to run, so was not able to run it

Comment: Is the state of 'user selected this item' reflected in the data underlying the ListView?

Comment: I don't want to collect that data (whether user has selected that item or not)

Comment: but somehow the activity has to keep track of the disappeared icons

Comment: I don't mind even if the icon disappears, all I want is, I want this icon in list  to slide to that blue icon on top, and disappear.